# Apache Server or PHP remove Postvars containing a long text

Tags: apache-2.2, php

There's a postvar send to Server which gets fully removed if size reached a level.
If the ammount of text in that var has a size of 66kb or greater the complete var gets deletet.

Smaller Texts e.g. 61kb size is pased into php.
Everything checked with wireshark before, and data definitly going out of my Client.

It's an apache Server with PHP+suhosinPatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cbeck your logs : if suhosin remove the data, it is written in your error log for your virtualhost. You will be able to configure it.
Check too if you don't oversize your PHP 'post_max_size' configuration.